# How to recieve image in a php server from an iphone

Tags: php, iphone, json, image, nsdata

I want to send a picture of my app to a web server. The problem is that I'm new to web services.

My app sends (via POST) an image as nsdata using json, but I don't have a clue how to convert this "nsdata" to a png or jpeg image using json on a php webservice. Does this have to do with base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just send a request to the image path, works great.

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPath]]];
```

this is the lazy way cause you'll pause the main thread with this request but if you do it in a secondary thread is fine I suppose. The right way is to use the NSURLConnectionDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to upload files in PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$uploaddir = "../xxx/";
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
echo "file=".$file; 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo $file;
}
else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```